# R, replace dataframe

Tags: r, replace, dataframe

```
> df1         
                                                  Var1  Freq
1                                                   L    30
2                                                   A    51
3                                                   B    99
4                                                   C    44
5                                                   D    31

> df2
                                                 Var1  Freq


3                                                   B    99
4                                                   C    44
5                                                   D    31
```

my question is I would like to get the result of  df1-df2
like

```
> df3
                                                  Var1  Freq
1                                                   L    30
2                                                   A    51
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try negation of intersection on the Var1 values:

```
df1[ !df1$Var1 %in% df2$Var1 , ]
```